# Logs from containers fails to send to aws cloudwatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

Needed a little help here. i have ec2 instance with installed docker, I'm trying to get logs from my containers via (docker-compose) but logs are not sending to AWS cloudwatch when I'm using docker-compose but it is successfully sending when I used docker run (docker run -it -p 91:80 -p 3306:3306 --log-driver="awslogs" --log-opt awslogs-region="ap-southeast-1" --log-opt awslogs-group="web-logs" --log-opt awslogs-stream="docker-run-php-logs" lamp:latest bash).

what I've done so far (Role, Policies, attaching IAM in ec2 instance and declared awslogs in /etc/docker, installed and configured awscli with user credentials) here's my docker-compose file https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZ9fA.jpg and also here's my Dockerfile https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKTrz.jpg

here's my daemon.json in /etc/docker

```
{
  "log-driver": "awslogs",
  "log-opts": {
    "awslogs-region": "ap-southeast-1",
    "awslogs-group": "web-logs"
  }
}
```

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? If yes, can you provide an answer?